# How to give return value of a function to print in Python

Tags: python

I am very new to python and I am trying to write a simple vacation program. In my program, the user is required to input city, number of days of vacation etc... and in the end I calculate the total cost, based on some simple calculations defined in few functions.

My problem is, I am not able to print the output of a particular function which has two input parameters, without adding the input parameters in the print statement !!!

But, since the user enters the values, I don't want to hardcode them.

```
def trip_cost(city, days,spending_money): 
  city = hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city) 
  days = rental_car_cost(days) 
  total_cost = city + days + spending_money 
  return total_cost
```

I am new and lost !!!

Kindly help me....

Comment: def trip_cost(city, days):
   city = hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city)
   days = rental_car_cost(days)
   total_cost = city + days
   return total_cost

Comment: How do I print total_cost in a statement like "( "Your trip cost for %s many days of stay in %s, when you rent a car for %s number of days is %? " % (days,city,car,?)    So - what EXACTLY should replace '?' here, so that the total cost is printed in the output without passing city, days in print ?

Comment: python 2 or 3?  print("Your trip cost for %s many days of stay in %s, when you rent a car for %s number of days is %s " % (days,city,car,cost))  look at the string formatters https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html and https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting

Comment: Python 2 - may be that's why its not working ??

Comment: That will work for python 2, depends on how you declare the variables and where in your program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function returns a value that can be passed as an argument to print() or a formatted string. For example:

```
print("Your %s day trip in %s is %0.2f dollars"%(days, city, trip_cost(city, days)))
```

EDIT:
Here's a complete example, which I adapted from your comment.

```
def plane_ride_cost(city): 
    if city =="Charlotte": 
        return 183 
    elif city == "Tampa": 
        return 220 
    elif city =="Pittsburgh": 
        return 222 
    elif city =="Los Angeles":
        return 475 
    else:
        raise ValueError("No Vacation")

def hotel_cost(days): 
    return 140*days

def rental_car_cost(days):
    return 30*days

def trip_cost(city, days):
    total_cost = 0.0
    total_cost += hotel_cost(days)
    total_cost += plane_ride_cost(city)
    total_cost += rental_car_cost(days)
    return total_cost

city=raw_input("Enter your destination")
days=int(raw_input("Enter the duration of your stay in number of days"))
print("Your %s day trip in %s is %0.2f dollars"%(days, city, trip_cost(city, days)))
```

Comment: city=raw_input("Enter your destination")

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city =="Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city =="Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city =="Los Angeles":
        return 475
    else:
        return "No Vacation"
        
days=raw_input("Enter the duration of your stay in number of days")

def hotel_cost(days):
    return 140*days
.
.
.
.
..
.
def trip_cost(city, days):
   city = hotel_cost(days) + plane_ride_cost(city)
   days = rental_car_cost(days)
   total_cost = city + days
   return total_cost

Comment: How do I print the "total_cost" in my print statement.

Comment: look at my comment and change cost to total_cost

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood your question, but you can print the specific values like so:

```
print("City: %s\nDays: %s\nSpending money: $%s\n") % (city,days,spending_money)
```

Assuming input was: NYC, 10, and 12345 respectively the output would be:

City: NYC

Days: 10

Spending money: $12345

Comment: this notation isn't compatible with python 3

Comment: city=raw_input("Enter your destination")

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    if city =="Charlotte":
        return 183
    elif city == "Tampa":
        return 220
    elif city =="Pittsburgh":
        return 222
    elif city =="Los Angeles":
        return 475
    else:
        return "No Vacation"
        
days=raw_input("Enter the duration of your stay in number of days")

def hotel_cost(days):
    return 140*days

Comment: I wish I could paste my code in some clear format - I know, it's not very clear from my question.

Answer (score 0):

Please clarify exactly what you want to print and what version of python you are using.

```
def trip_cost(city, days, spending_money):
    total_cost = hotel_cost(days) + plane_cost(city) + rental_car_cost(days) + spending_money 
    print "Total Cost: " + str(total_cost)
    return total_cost
```

Comment: I am using the old version - 2.7.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to calculate the total cost. In Python 3 then:

```
hotel_cost_amt = 200
rental_car_amt = 30
plane_ride_amt = {'city_A': 1200, 'city_B': 1100}

def hotel_cost(days):
    return days * hotel_cost_amt

def plane_ride_cost(city):
    return plane_ride_amt[city]

def rental_car_cost(days):
    return rental_car_amt * days

def trip_cost(city, days,spending_money): 
    return hotel_cost(days) + \
        plane_ride_cost(city) + \
        rental_car_cost(days) + \
        spending_money

if __name__ == '__main__':
    days = 7
    city = 'city_A'
    spending_money = 2000

    print('Your trip cost for %i many days of stay in %s, when you rent a car for %i number of days is %i. This includes %i spending money.' % \
        (
            days,
            city,
            days,
            trip_cost(city, days, spending_money),
            spending_money
        )
    )
```

The function the way you defined it wouldn't work. For Python 2 use

```
print 'Your trip cost for %i many days of stay in %s, when you rent a car for %i number of days is %i. This includes %i spending money.' % \
        (
            days,
            city,
            days,
            trip_cost(city, days, spending_money),
            spending_money
        )
```

Comment: How do I combine raw_input here ? Like, when I am asking the user to input numbers and names. I tried modifying my code as per your suggestion, it is compiling fine, but I am not getting any output from print !!! I think, I need to try it in Python3. Thanks for your help.

Comment: What are you asking the user to input that you later raw_input into? Remember, that raw_input is a string so you need to cast it into either integer (using int(raw_input)) or float: float(raw_input).

Comment: Does this function look good to you(just by itself) or something is missing - car=raw_input("Enter the number of days when you will rent a car")

def rental_car_cost(days):
    cost = 40*days
    if days >=7:
        cost-=50
    elif days >=3:
        cost-=20
            
    return cost

Comment: Nope, it should be car_days=int(raw_input("Enter the number of car rental days: "))    Then call rental_car_cost(car_days) The function itself looks ok as long as I understand it without indents.